# What happens if a promise completes before then is called?

Tags: javascript, promise

Let's say I have a `Promise` like this:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Do some async thing
});
promise.then(function(response) {
    // Then do some other stuff
});
```

What happens if the `async` `Promise` completes before I call `.then()`? Normally, I'd only have long running tasks in the `Promise` function, but what if it completes really quickly one time?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

As expected: then callback will get called immediately in this case if then was called after promise has already resolved.

It's easy to test:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(123);
});

setTimeout(function() {
  promise.then(function(response) {
      alert(response);
  });
}, 1000)
```

Comment: "immediately" is a bit misleading in this case or at the best, not descriptive enough.  It is called soon, but still called asynchronously.  All `.then()` handlers are always called asynchronously with promises per the promise spec.  So, a line of code right after `promise.then(...)` will get executed BEFORE the `.then()` handler function gets called, even if the promise is already resolved.

Comment: What jFriend says but with the proviso that jQuery promises are non-standard. One of the mayor criticisms of jQuery is that a `then()` chained to an already settled promise will fire its success or error callback synchronously in the same event thread. We understand that this behaviour will be fixed in jQuery v3.

Comment: "immediately" is indeed misleading. for example, `Promise.resolve(11).then(console.log); console.log(22);`
prints `22 11`

Answer (score 18):

As others have already pointed out, you can add callbacks with `.then` before or after the promise has been resolved, and you can even add more than one callback.

These callbacks will be called in the order they were added, but always asynchronously, *after* the current turn of the event loop. So if the promise has already been resolved when you add a `.then`, your handler will be called immediately, but in the "ascynchronous sense".

The [Promises/A+ spec](https://github.com/promises-aplus/promises-spec) says:

> [...] `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` execute asynchronously, after the event loop turn in which `then` is called, and with a fresh stack.

Answer (score 8):

A promise has state, which means that even after the promise gets fulfilled, you can attach callbacks using `.then` to it, and they will be called, with the same result as if the promise was fulfilled after they were attached.

Fulfilled is the final state of a successful promise. This means that you can attach more handlers to the fulfilled promise in the future, using the promise as a cache for the original response.

[.then() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise)

> then()
>
> Calls one of the provided functions as soon as this promise is either
>   fulfilled or rejected. A new promise is returned, whose state evolves
>   depending on this promise and the provided callback functions.
>
> The appropriate callback is always invoked after this method returns,
>   even if this promise is already fulfilled or rejected.  You can also
>   call the then method multiple times on the same promise, and the
>   callbacks will be invoked in the same order as they were registered.

Answer (score 2):

The `then` callback will never get called before the promise is `resolved`, which is what I think you mean by complete. However, if a promise is resolved before it is returned from a function, any additional success callbacks chained after that moment will still be executed. For example,

```
function getMeAResolvedPromise() {
    var prom = new Promise();
    prom.resolve('some val');
    return prom;
}

...

getMeAResolvedPromise.then(function(result) {
    // this will still be executed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one mention the MicroTasks queue.

**Even a *resolved* promised `.then` doesn't execute right away**:

```js
const prom = Promise.resolve(11); // value's ready

prom.then(console.log); 

console.log(22); 

// prints 22 11
```

Calling `.then` on a resolved promise schedules a microtask, that will be executed when the call stack becomes empty.

Comment: It is mentioned in pdenes' answer, a comment on dfsq's answer, and in the mdn quote in oridrori's answer.